# Why some characters overflow a line despite using font-size == line-height?

Tags: html, css

```html
<div style="height:40px; line-height:40px; width:40px; font-size: 40px; font-family: sans-serif; background-color:rgb(220,220,220)">
  ⇪
<div>
```

Running that snippet on Chrome, macOS Sierra, displays:

[image]

Notice the arrow overflows the div. I thought that could never happen. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the font-size does not define the height of the glyph, but the height of the em-square. Its normal in fonts for glyphs to be taller than the em-square.

Every font has an em-square size and an ascent and a descent. The glyph will typically fit between the distance from the top of the ascent and the bottom of the descent, but that distance is often larger than the em-square size.

Comment: Just for completion: it can be arbitrarily larger? Is there a safe `font-size / line-height` ratio I can use to guarantee that the glyph will not overflow (or at least the majority of the common glyphs)?

Comment: The em-square size can be set completely independently of the ascent and descent values. Typically, browsers use a ratio of around 1.2 to 1.25 as a default line-height, which works for most common fonts, but there's no value that can be guaranteed to work with every font.

Comment: If you're interested [Type-light](http://www.cr8software.net/typelight.html) is a decent, free tool for experimenting with fonts. You can adjust with the various values so you can see how the various height values interact.